# Angular Momentum in Quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, operators

In Gasiorowicz's *Quantum Physics*, we determined the relation: $$L_z | l,m\rangle= \hbar m | l,m \rangle$$

I would like to determine: $\langle l,m_1 | L_x | l,m_2 \rangle $

I thought about expressing $L_x$ in terms of $L_{+}$ and  $L_{-}$, which gives us:

$$L_x= \frac12\left(L_{+}+ L_{-}\right)$$

We know that: 
$$L_{+} | l,m\rangle= C_{+} | l,m+1 \rangle$$ 
and 
$$L_{-} | l,m\rangle= C_{-} | l,m-1 \rangle$$

But I don't think that's how I should proceed.

Comment: You're doing exactly the right thing.  Keep going.

Comment: @joshphysics But we have in one ket we have $m+1$ and in the other $m-1$

Comment: Equation (7.52) will be useful (assuming 3rd edition of Gasiorowicz).

Comment: It's fine. You will have to compute the inner product of the $m$ and $m-1$ states. Bear in mind that the $|l,m>$ is an eigenstate of the $z$ component of angular momentum, which does *not* commute with the $x$ component, so all you'll get from $<L_x>$ is a superposition.

Comment: @Harold why inner product ?

Comment: @Carpediem: $\langle l',m'|l,m\rangle$ is an inner product

Comment: I still don't understand because my final result is $\frac{C_{+}+C_{-}}{2}(\langle l,m_1 \mid l,m_2+1 \rangle+ \langle l,m_1 \mid l, m_2 -1 \rangle$ Where do I go from here ?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that you've gotten to Chapter 7 (Angular Momentum) without having gone through Chapter 6 (Operator Methods). Skim Chapter 6 for the phrase "orthonormality condition"

Comment: @KyleKanos The orthonormality condition is $\langle x \mid x' \rangle= \delta(x-x')$

Comment: I'd say that from there you need the explicit form of the eigenstates

Comment: @Carpediem: How about in terms of quantum numbers?

Comment: the expression he gets is already in terms of the quantum numbers, is it not?

Answer (score 1):

You had the right idea, just need to keep going. With $C_\pm=\hbar\sqrt{\ell_2(\ell_2+1)- m_2(m_2\pm1)}$ you have
$$\langle\ell_1,m_1|L_x|\ell_2,m_2\rangle=\left\langle\ell_1,m_1\left|\frac{1}{2}(L_++L_-)\right|\ell_2,m_2\right\rangle\\=\frac{1}{2}\left(\left\langle\ell_1,m_1|L_+|\ell_2,m_2\right\rangle+\left\langle\ell_1,m_1|L_+|\ell_2,m_2\right\rangle\right)
\\
=\frac{1}{2}\left(C_+\langle\ell_1,m_1|\ell_2,m_2+1\rangle+C_-\langle\ell_1,m_1|\ell_2,m_2-1\rangle\right)
\\
=\frac{1}{2}\left(C_+\delta_{m_1,m_2+1}\delta_{\ell_1,\ell_2}+C_-\delta_{m_1,m_2-1}\delta_{\ell_1,\ell_2}\right).$$
The matrix representation of $L_x$ in the $\{|\ell,-\ell\rangle,...,|\ell,\ell\rangle\}$ basis then admits a block-diagonal form, with the $\ell$th block $\mathbf{L}_x^\ell$ given for the first few values of $\ell$ by
$$\mathbf{L}_x^0=0
\\
\mathbf{L}_x^1=\frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2}}\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\\
\mathbf{L}_x^2=\frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2}}\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & \sqrt{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \sqrt{2} & 0 & \sqrt{3} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \sqrt{3} & 0 & \sqrt{3} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \sqrt{3} & 0 & \sqrt{2} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{2} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\\
\mathbf{L}_x^3=\frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2}}\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 0 & \sqrt{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \sqrt{3} & 0 & \sqrt{5} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \sqrt{5} & 0 & \sqrt{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \sqrt{6} & 0 & \sqrt{6} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{6} & 0 & \sqrt{5} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{5} & 0 & \sqrt{3} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{3} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\\
\mathbf{L}_x^4=\frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2}}\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 2 & 0 & \sqrt{7} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \sqrt{7} & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & \sqrt{10} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{10} & 0 & \sqrt{10} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{10} & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & \sqrt{7} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{7} & 0 & 2 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\\
\mathbf{L}_x^5=\frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2}}\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
 0 & \sqrt{5} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \sqrt{5} & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 3 & 0 & 2 \sqrt{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 2 \sqrt{3} & 0 & \sqrt{14} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{14} & 0 & \sqrt{15} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{15} & 0 & \sqrt{15} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{15} & 0 & \sqrt{14} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{14} & 0 & 2 \sqrt{3} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \sqrt{3} & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & \sqrt{5} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{5} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and so on.

#### Code

Just FYI, the following `Mathematica` code generates the above six matrices:

```
Cp[l_, m_] := \[HBar] Sqrt[l (l + 1) - m (m + 1)];
Cm[l_, m_] := \[HBar] Sqrt[l (l + 1) - m (m - 1)];
Map[MatrixForm, Sqrt[2]/\[HBar] Table[1/2 (Cp[L, m2] KroneckerDelta[m1, m2 + 1] + Cm[L, m2] KroneckerDelta[m1, m2 - 1]), {L, 0, 5}, {m1, -L, L}, {m2, -L, L}]]
```